# Django: How to return a clean list from db for charts.js?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to update charts.js with info from my database. To do that in my view i have this:

```
def processCharts(request):
    process = ProcessInfo.objects.values_list('process_name')
    process_list = list(process)

    context = {'process_list' : process_list, }
    return render(request, 'process/charts.html', context)
```

i would like to retrive a list i can put into charts.js and that looks like this

```
labels: ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6', 'Option7'],
```

When i render process_list on charts.js i get a messy list like the one below:

```
labels: [(&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;,), (&#x27;dsas aasdasds&#x27;,), (&#x27;Test user 2&#x27;,), (&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;,), (&#x27;Test user 2&#x27;,), (&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;,), (&#x27;Test user 2&#x27;,), (&#x27;Test user 2&#x27;,), (&#x27;Recivabel&#x27;,), (&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;,), (&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;,), (&#x27;Cash app v 123&#x27;,), (&#x27;Recruiting&#x27;,), (&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;,)],
```

How can I clean my queryset or the objects from the database to get a clean list for charts.js ?

Comment: try to use: `ProcessInfo.objects.values_list('process_name', flat=True)`

Comment: that helped a lot but for some reason inside the charts js code it renders the appostropho like this : labels: [&#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;, &#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;, &#x27;Accounts Recivabel&#x27;]

Comment: how looks your charts.html?